# How can I get data after changing pages on AJAX when using python/selenium?

Tags: python, ajax, selenium

I'm trying to get some data from a site but am having a bit of problems getting data when I change pages.  I get the data I want when I first go to the page but as I click to other pages(ajax clicks) I keep getting the old data.

I am not sure I understand the logic of how to do this is selenium.  I get a page via webdriver then process the data. I click on a link and send the webdriver instance back to be process yet it contains only the old data.

For example:

```
Page 1
1
2
3
Page 2:
4
5
6
```

I can process page 1 and get data(1,2,3) but when I click on the second page(which I can see is opening) I still get 1,2,3 as the results.

If it helps, here's my code(instead of getting different data on each page I'm getting the same on every page):

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import time
# Firefox
#driver = webdriver.Firefox()

# Google Chrome
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.theglobeandmail.com/globe-investor/markets/stocks/financials/?q=RY-T&page=incomeStatement&frequency=ANNUAL#financials-content')

def scraper(driver): #get the data out
    rawData = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="a-stockFinancials_tabs"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td')
    print rawData[50].get_attribute("innerHTML") #get operating income: 11,081.00 is for year 2013 only, 18,778.00  for 2009,etc..
    # for element in rawData:
    #     print element.get_attribute("innerHTML")
    print '*** Done a page ****'

#start
scraper(driver)
#number of tabs:
numberOfentries = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="a-stockFinancials_tabs"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]')
#get the number of buttons listed there
testList = os.linesep.join([s for s in numberOfentries[0].get_attribute("innerHTML").splitlines() if s])
countButtons = len(testList.splitlines()) -3 #remove 2 because of the forward/backward button count and take 1 more extra because we start on page 1 and if there is 4 pages then we need only need to move forward 3 pages
for clicks in range(0,countButtons):
    print clicks
    driver.find_element_by_id('a-stockFinancials_link_incomeStatement_ANNUAL_next').click() #driver.find_elements_by_xpath("xpath=//a[contains(@id,'a-stockFinancials_link_incomeStatement_ANNUAL_next')")
    time.sleep(1)
    scraper(driver)
driver.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the information you're looking for is already on that page and isn't being loaded via ajax.

```
<li class="page_2" style="overflow: hidden; float: left; width: 400px; height: 1104px;">
```

So you don't even need to find out how many links are there.
You just need to loop through class="page_*".

rawData = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="a-stockFinancials_tabs"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/ul/li[@class="page_1"]/div/table/tbody/tr/td')
print rawData[50].get_attribute("innerHTML")

would work. But you could also look around for each [@class="page_*"]